# Is there a real number lookup algorithm or service?

Tags: math-software, experimental-mathematics

Is there a way of taking a number known to limited precision (e.g. $1.644934$) and finding out an "interesting" real number (e.g. $\displaystyle\frac{\pi^2}{6}$) that's close to it?

I'm thinking of something like Sloane's Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, only for real numbers.

The intended use would be: write a program to calculate an approximation to $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$, look up the answer ("looks close to $\displaystyle\frac{\pi^2}{6}$") and then use the likely answer to help find a proof that the sum really is $\displaystyle \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.644934). It actually does sequences as well.

Comment: Wow, that's... amazing. Exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: That is not [all it does](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=new+york+city)...

Answer (score 25):

I've long used Simon Plouffe's [inverse symbolic calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html) for this purpose.  It is essentially a searchable list of "interesting" numbers.

Edit: link updated (Mar 2022).

Comment: I'd been using http://pi.lacim.uqam.ca/eng/ but your link looks like a much-updated version, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the decimal digits of numbers will appear in Sloane's On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences [OIES](http://oeis.org/).

E.g. [here](http://oeis.org/A000796) is the decimal expansion of pi.